# How to set the value of textbox to 0 if blank if checkbox is not clicked

Tags: php, jquery

I am going to start learn jquery with php.I have form(Which i copied from google)

```js
$('document').ready(function() {
  $('.toggleswitch').bootstrapToggle();
  $("#check1 .stars").click(function() {
    $(this).attr("checked");
  });

});
```

```css
/****** Rating Starts *****/

@import url(http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/3.2.1/css/font-awesome.css);
fieldset,
label {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

body {
  margin: 20px;
}

h1 {
  font-size: 1.5em;
  margin: 10px;
}

.rating {
  border: none;
  float: left;
}

.rating>input {
  display: none;
}

.rating>label:before {
  margin: 5px;
  font-size: 1.25em;
  font-family: FontAwesome;
  display: inline-block;
  content: "\f005";
}

.rating>.half:before {
  content: "\f089";
  position: absolute;
}

.rating>label {
  color: #ddd;
  float: right;
}

.rating>input:checked~label,
.rating:not(:checked)>label:hover,
.rating:not(:checked)>label:hover~label {
  color: #FFD700;
}

.rating>input:checked+label:hover,
.rating>input:checked~label:hover,
.rating>label:hover~input:checked~label,
.rating>input:checked~label:hover~label {
  color: #FFED85;
}


/* Downloaded from http://devzone.co.in/ */
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-toggle/2.2.2/css/bootstrap-toggle.min.css" />
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-toggle/2.2.2/js/bootstrap2-toggle.min.js"></script>
<form action="" method="POST" />
<fieldset id='check1' class="rating">
  <input class="stars" type="radio" id="star_a-5" name="rating" value="5" />
  <label class="full" for="star5" title="Awesome - 5 stars"></label>
  <input class="stars" type="radio" id="star_a_5-half" name="rating" value="4.5" />
  <label class="half" for="star4half" title="Pretty good - 4.5 stars"></label>
  <input class="stars" type="radio" id="star_a-4" name="rating" value="4" />
  <label class="full" for="star4" title="Pretty good - 4 stars"></label>
  <input class="stars" type="radio" id="star_a_4-half" name="rating" value="3.5" />
  <label class="half" for="star3half" title="Meh - 3.5 stars"></label>
  <input class="stars" type="radio" id="star_a-3" name="rating" value="3" />
  <label class="full" for="star3" title="Meh - 3 stars"></label>
  <input class="stars" type="radio" id="star_a_3-half" name="rating" value="2.5" />
  <label class="half" for="star2half" title="Kinda bad - 2.5 stars"></label>
  <input class="stars" type="radio" id="star2" name="rating" value="2" />
  <label class="full" for="star2" title="Kinda bad - 2 stars"></label>
  <input class="stars" type="radio" id="star1half" name="rating" value="1.5" />
  <label class="half" for="star1half" title="Meh - 1.5 stars"></label>
  <input class="stars" type="radio" id="star1" name="rating" value="1" />
  <label class="full" for="star1" title="Sucks big time - 1 star"></label>
  <input class="stars" type="radio" id="starhalf" name="rating" value="0.5" />
  <label class="half" for="starhalf" title="Sucks big time - 0.5 stars"></label>
</fieldset>
<br>

<input type="submit" onclick="setValue()" name="btn_submit" value="submit" />
</div>
```

using this PHP:

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['btn_submit']))
{
    echo '<pre>';
    print_r($_POST);
}

?>
```

This form is working fine.If i click star rate and submit button I got output like

```
 Array
(
    [rating] => 1
    [btn_submit] => submit
)
```

And if i am not select any rating output will be like

```
Array
    (

        [btn_submit] => submit
    )
```

**But i expect**

```
Array
        (
            [rating] => 0
            [btn_submit] => submit
        )
```

I tried

```
 function setValue()
        {
             var input = document.getElementById('check1');

     if(input.value.length == '')
    input.value = 0;
        }
```

If i am not click star rate input field is set to 0?How can i do if i have more text input like check2 check3 check4 using **jquery**?I want to set all input text field as 0 before send data if rating is not clicked.Please help me?As a beginner please forgive if had make any mistake

Comment: If you don't check any checkbox it will not post values of server side

Comment: @PankajMakwana:Then how can i set it..please help me..

Comment: @teststack I have added an [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45079490/4939819)

Comment: I created a snippet for you. It does not run the PHP but just to show you how to make a [mcve]

Comment: @mplungjan Sir please give me link

Comment: I CONVERTED your code into a snippet using the `<>` snippet editor button

Answer (score 1):

This will not post as parameter to server, If you don't check any check-box

Additionaly you can check in PHP files, that is it posted or not.

Try

```
if(isset($_POST['btn_submit']))
{
    $_POST['rating'] = isset($_POST['rating']) ? $_POST['rating'] : '0';
    echo '<pre>';
    print_r($_POST);
```

Comment: @hassan-Thanks for your answer but i want to check it with jquery?is it possible

Comment: @teststack Try to replace `input.value = 0;` with `$('input#check1').val('0');`

Answer (score 1):

just add condition first in PHP like below

```
if(!isset($_POST['rating'])){
   $_POST['rating'] = 0;
}
print_r($_POST);
```

Answer (score 1):

Do not use the submit button to check the value - instead set the value and user the submit event of the form to check

I also had to remove the bootstrap which was not used AND change the IDs of the radios

When hitting the server you need to check that submit was set but no radio passed. Then that means 0 - right now my jQuery does not allow submission if not rated - I gave the form an ID

```js
$('document').ready(function() {
  $("#myForm").on("submit",function(e) {
     if($("#check1 .stars:checked").length==0) {
       alert("Please rate");
       e.preventDefault();
     }
  })
});
```

```css
/****** Rating Starts *****/
@import url(https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/3.2.1/css/font-awesome.css);

fieldset,
label {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

body {
  margin: 20px;
}

h1 {
  font-size: 1.5em;
  margin: 10px;
}

.rating {
  border: none;
  float: left;
}

.rating>input {
  display: none;
}

.rating>label:before {
  margin: 5px;
  font-size: 1.25em;
  font-family: FontAwesome;
  display: inline-block;
  content: "\f005";
}

.rating>.half:before {
  content: "\f089";
  position: absolute;
}

.rating>label {
  color: #ddd;
  float: right;
}

.rating>input:checked~label,
.rating:not(:checked)>label:hover,
.rating:not(:checked)>label:hover~label {
  color: #FFD700;
}

.rating>input:checked+label:hover,
.rating>input:checked~label:hover,
.rating>label:hover~input:checked~label,
.rating>input:checked~label:hover~label {
  color: #FFED85;
}


/* Downloaded from http://devzone.co.in/ */
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<form id="myForm" action="" method="POST" />
<fieldset id='check1' class="rating toggleswitch">
  <input class="stars" type="radio" id="star5" name="rating" value="5" data-toggle="toggle"/>
  <label class="full" for="star5" title="Awesome - 5 stars"></label>
  <input class="stars" type="radio" id="star4half" name="rating" value="4.5" data-toggle="toggle"/>
  <label class="half" for="star4half" title="Pretty good - 4.5 stars"></label>
  <input class="stars" type="radio" id="star4" name="rating" value="4" data-toggle="toggle"/>
  <label class="full" for="star4" title="Pretty good - 4 stars"></label>
  <input class="stars" type="radio" id="star3half" name="rating" value="3.5" data-toggle="toggle"/>
  <label class="half" for="star3half" title="Meh - 3.5 stars"></label>
  <input class="stars" type="radio" id="star3" name="rating" value="3" data-toggle="toggle"/>
  <label class="full" for="star3" title="Meh - 3 stars"></label>
  <input class="stars" type="radio" id="star2half" name="rating" value="2.5" data-toggle="toggle"/>
  <label class="half" for="star2half" title="Kinda bad - 2.5 stars"></label>
  <input class="stars" type="radio" id="star2" name="rating" value="2" />
  <label class="full" for="star2" title="Kinda bad - 2 stars"></label>
  <input class="stars" type="radio" id="star1half" name="rating" value="1.5" data-toggle="toggle"/>
  <label class="half" for="star1half" title="Meh - 1.5 stars"></label>
  <input class="stars" type="radio" id="star1" name="rating" value="1" data-toggle="toggle" />
  <label class="full" for="star1" title="Sucks big time - 1 star"></label>
  <input class="stars" type="radio" id="starhalf" name="rating" value="0.5" data-toggle="toggle"/>
  <label class="half" for="starhalf" title="Sucks big time - 0.5 stars"></label>
</fieldset>
<br>

<input type="submit" name="btn_submit" value="submit" />
</div>
```